# DECK.GL Right Click Event

Tags: layer, right-click, deck.gl

After uploading a layer with deck.gl and right clicking on a shape, the event is not triggered.

onClick: (info, event) => console.log(event.rightButton)

The above line does not work. Does someone have a better approach for triggering the right click event?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's onClick and not onclick?

Comment: Forgot to add pickable property to the layer?

Comment: Pickable is set to true and changing onClick to onclick does not make it work

Comment: Try to put some code, because I am not able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?